# Automate Excel entry every 30 days

Tags: microsoft-excel

I get money in my account every 30 days gap. 
Starting from 5-12-2019. then every 30 days gap I get 5000 in my account. I don't withdraw anything from it. So it's saving account.

Can I make an excel file in which automatically after every 30 days gap a new entry is added under columns: **date, balance added**.

I want automate process so that whenever I open the excel file it's automatically updated.

Columns I want to add: **Date, Credit, Balance.** Initially, balance was 1000 on 5-12-2019, i.e. first credit of 5000. Then every 30 days I want it to update automatically.

It's actually a interest I get every month from my fixed deposit.

Comment: It's a real challenge,, to automate the task every month, actually U need Macro (VBA code) to perform the job on fixed Date, if you are comfortable with Macro please [edit] your post and add few line at bottom that you need both, Non VBA as well as VBA solution,, also add new TAG `VBA` to the question. otherwise I can show U worksheet method to do the same, please confirm though comments!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a formula like the following in the Date column:

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR(EDATE(I1,1)>TODAY(),TRUE),I1=""),"",EDATE(I1,1))
```

The key is to make the cell have "nothing" in it, so it looks empty/blank when the corresponding date has not come into existence BUT in a way that the very next cell and then all following it have error results. The first portion does that then the second portion (if the `IF()` has a FALSE result (date does not exist yet) will add one month to the date above it.

So nothing displays for the date cell if the date it would have does not exist yet.

Then the following two cells would have formulas that first look at the value of that row's date cell, returning a blank if the date cell is blank, or returning the appropriate thing if it has a date showing. ("Appropriate thing" woul dbe the crediting ammount for the Credit column and a sum of the Balance result on the line above and the credit amount of the line. So perhaps:  (credit amount is perhaps 50 and the starting deposit perhaps 2000 for the example)

```
=IF(I2="","",50)
```

and

```
=IF(I2="","",K1+J2)
```

Note that it's a ton of pain to write these to accomodate the first row so one usually puts straightforward calculations in the first row, then uses this kind of formula set for all the following rows.

Now, when you open the file, that day's date is calculated by `TODAY() in all the date cells and compared to the date it calculates should be there. Close it today and it would show 12 rows (the first and one for the 11 months following the opening date). Open the file again on September 1st and it will show rows for May, June, July, and August as well, and of course, the credit and balance data for the rows as well.